# How to add some values and then subtract them using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am taking values from database in my input boxes and then add the values. There are some input fields which deduct the values; I have written the code but it's not working, its only giving me the sum up values but not doing subtraction. Kindly help me.

```js
<script type ="text/javascript">
 
 $(document).ready(function(){
 
        //iterate through each textboxes and add keyup
        //handler to trigger sum event
        $(".text").each(function() {
 
            $(this).on('input',function(){
                calculateSum();
            });
        });
    
        // call calculateSum function after typing in subtract field
        $('.sub').on('input',calculateSum);
 
    });

    // function for subtracting from total
    function totalSubtract(sumTotal) {
     
      var subtract = parseFloat($('.sub').val());
         sumTotal -= subtract;
         return sumTotal;
    }
 
    function calculateSum() {
 
        //console.log('calc');
        
        var total = 0;
        //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
        $(".text").each(function() {
 
            //add only if the value is number
            if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) {
                total += parseFloat(this.value);
            }
        });
        
        // subtract from total
        total = totalSubtract(total);
        
        //.toFixed() method will roundoff the final sum to 2 decimal places
        $("#amount").val(total.toFixed(2));
    }
  
    </script>
```

Comment: Your script is confusing. In document ready also you are calling $(".text").each and in CaculateSum also you are using the same. Again, you are calling totalSubtract within calculateSum as well as in the document ready.  Please review the flow and change it accordingly. If possible provide the sample HTML code along.

Comment: actually i amm new in jquery so what will be the correct sequence of my program in your way and i am calling .txt class text boxes because it changes the value on selection other employes so everytime it changes it will give me sum

Comment: well i soeted my own basicaly the problem is in the Totalsubtrac function and thanx for answering my question

Comment: Glad that helped.